# Oracle database on VirtualBox VM or Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, virtualbox

I am trying to get a Oracle database to be used for development purposes. I want to reduce the footprint of the database on the host (Windows).

Would it be better using a VirtualBox VM or a Docker container?

I'm guessing that the Docker container will not give me any substantial advantage as I'm going to need a Linux kernel anyway so I'm leaning toward the VM option.

Also is there any in-memory databases which can successfully mock Oracle databases? If so what editions?

Comment: Running a docker container in Windows currently requires VirtualBox (default) or some other VM that can run a Linux OS.

Comment: SQLite can successfully mock an Oracle database up to a certain point if you're careful about your query syntax.

Comment: Oracle offers prebuilt VM images. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

Comment: This is very late, but for reference: the benefit of docker, even in a VM, is that you can still run up multiple instances of Oracle, and thus more accurately model an organisation that uses multiple SIDs. You could do this with one VM per instance, but this is a heavyweight solution for which you'll need a significantly higher spec machine than the equivalent, lightweight, docker solution.